# How to create a shortcode with HTML code in it and custom parameters/

Tags: customization, shortcode, html

I want to create a shortcode for putting newsletter opt-in boxes in my posts and pages. But depending on the page or post, I want to have different headline and description for the opt-in box.

I created a *shortcode-newsletter.php* file with this code in it:

```
<?php

function newsletter(){

return <<<HTML

    <div class="newsletterForm">

        <h3>Newsletter Box Headline</h3>

        <p>Newsletter Box Description</p>

        <form method="post" action="https://domain.com/newsletter/z2o7q6">

            <input type="hidden" name="ml-submit" value="1">

                <div class="newsletterFields">

                    <div class="newsletterEmail">

                        <input required="" type="email" class="newsletterInput" name="fields[email]"
                            placeholder="Your email...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="newsletterButton">

                        <input type="submit" class="newsletterSubmit" value="Subscribe">

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="newsletterDisclaimer">

                    <p>Newsletter Box Disclaimer</p>

            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
HTML;
}
?>
```

In functions.php I added:

```
include('shortcode-newsletter.php');
add_shortcode( 'newsletter', 'newsletter' );
```

Now I want to have a shortcode with custom parameters:

```
[newsletter url="formActionUrl" headline="newsletterHeadline" description="newsletterDescription"]
```

But I don't know how to change the first code to have those parameters customizable.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the shortcode documentation, your shortcode callback recieves any parameters set by  the user in a `$atts` variable. You can combine them with any default values you might have with `shortcode_atts()`.

```
function newsletter( $atts ) {

  $atts = shortcode_atts( 
    array(
      'url'         => 'https://domain.com/newsletter/z2o7q6', // change default value as needed
      'headline'    => 'Newsletter Box Headline', // change default value as needed
      'description' => 'Newsletter Box Description', // change default value as needed
    ), 
    $atts, 
    'newsletter' 
  );

  // you can access parameters with $atts['url'], $atts['headline'], and $atts['description']
  // e.g <h3><?php echo esc_html($atts['headline']); ?></h3>

}
```